# Update NumericalFunction in NDSolve

Tags: interpolation, differential-equations

I have `NDSolve`` `StateData` from an `NDSolve`` `ProcessEquations` evaluation. I can `NDSolve`` `Iterate` from t0 to t1, but then my boundary condition (an interpolation function) runs out of data.

This interpolation function gets updated externally. I just want to continue iterating (t1 to t2) with the updated interpolation function. However, calling myStateData@`"NumericalFunction"` shows that NDSolve holds onto the old interpolation function, even though this function is defined with a delayed set i.e. myInterpFunction[t_]:=something[t]

Is there any way to update the functions inside of the state data?

Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
myStateData = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
    {myPDE[x,t],
    (*boundary conditions*)
    T[xf, t] == myInterpolationFunction[t],
    T[0, t] == 0,
    (*Initial condition*)
    T[x, t0] == initialCondition[x]};
    T, t, {x, 0, xf}]
```

Then I need to solve so...

```
NDSolve`Iterate[myStateData,t1]
```

Then externally I update my boundary condition so that now it goes to t2 but when I evaluate

```
NDSolve`Iterate[myStateData,t2]
```

Mathematica returns an error saying that the interpolation function doesn't cover that range (t1 - t2) because it's holding onto the old interpolating function. In other words, looking at

```
myStateData@"NumericalFunction"
```

shows myInterpolationFunction has a domain of {t0,t1}

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please include your actual code, or a simplified version of it if practical, so that readers can understand what you are doing.

Comment: I've added simplified code. My interpolation function is good from "t0" to "t1", once I update the function to go to "t2" I need NDSolve to continue Iterating/integrating to t2

Comment: Try `myInterpolationFunction[t_?NumericQ] := something[t]`.  See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037

Comment: Thanks Michael, but that's not the issue. The interpolation function is completely numeric, but NDSolve isn't getting the latest version with the larger domain (t1 - t2).

Comment: It works for me, for reasons that have to do with how *Mathematica* evaluates expressions and has nothing to do with interpolating functions being numeric.  Did you try it?  I can update the function `something[t]` to a new interpolating function and the extend the integration by `NDSolve`, which automatically uses the new interpolating function.  I thought that's what you wanted to do?

Comment: (If you did try it and it did not work, then I suggest it is because the problem is not sufficiently described in the question.  There must be something in the missing details that causes an unanticipated problem.)

Comment: Michael, I tried it, but the code is more complex than what I showed so I can do some more troubleshooting. Thanks for confirming you understand the problem. Can you also confirm that you're changing the domain of the interpolation function? I can run just fine, but since I'm using a time outside of the (original) interpolation function it says it needs to extrapolate, that's the only indication that it was running with the wrong interpolation function

Comment: Michael, I've confirmed you're not smoking crack. I tested on a simpler NDSolve problem and was able to pick up the extended interpolation function. I tested first with t_?NumericQ and haven't tried t_ alone with the simple problem. Now to go fix the original NDSolve. Thanks for the help, how do I promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: @EricWilliamSmith  You need to put an @ in front of non-author comments as I show here, or the person won't be notified of your response.  Authors are automatically notified.  I can write my comment up as an answer, but probably tomorrow.  It's too late right now.  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)